# What about Adding org-syntax as Alternative Native Markup for Questions and Answers on Emacs.SE Website

Tags: feature-request, markdown

#### History

When submitting questions and answers to the Emacs.SE , I usually write the text in org-syntax which I export into markdown syntax in a buffer and paste into the website forms.

On GitHub and GitLab, org-syntax is allowed by default as an alternative to the ubiquitous markdown. Both websites use the org-ruby gem to perform the conversion to markdown automatically on the back-end. I find the ability to use org-syntax on those websites very convenient.

#### Question

What about adding org-syntax as alternative native markup for questions and answers on Emacs.SE website?

Unfortunately, I don't know if this feature would be possible to implement on Emacs.SE, or if other users want it.

Thanks for your help!